# Django ORM get by ID - do I need to convert Id to Int?

Tags: django, django-orm

Do I need to convert `this_object_id` to int before I can pass to `id`?

```
obj = Class.objects.get(id=this_object_id)
```

Why or why not?

Comment: Why don't try it out yourself?

Comment: i did, i just trying to find the reason, it work on both ways, but should it is necessary to do it and convert it to int?

Comment: Not necessary if the field is returned as an int.  What fieldtype is id in your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accepts both. Ultimately you are building an SQL query statement, so passing an int that gets converted to a string or a string that gets inserted both work. See http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/models/lookups.html#lookup-reference for the lhs and rhs sides of the clause that is being constructed.